# Nodejs user authentication sql command

Tags: mysql, node.js

i am trying to make user authentication form in node.js with express.

currently i am using this query to insert in my db.

```
var  username = req.body.username;
var  password = req.body.password;


connection.query('USE one');
  connection.query("INSERT INTO users(id,name,pass) VALUES (1,"+ username +","+password+")", 
    function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
    }
);
```

my db structure is

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pass  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Please help i am getting an error:-

> throw err;
>         ^ Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'jjhk' in 'field list'

Answer (score -1):

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO users(id,name,pass) VALUES (1,"+ username +","+password+")"
```

should be

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO users(id,name,pass) VALUES (1,'"+ username +"','"+password+"')"
```

Comment: i would also be remiss if i didn't mention that it looks like you're saving your password in plaintext, and that is verybad.

Comment: can you tell me how  i can encrypt the user password in MD5 hash using node.js ??

Comment: Also possible for SQL injection here.  -1

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your using the node-mysql module.  To avoid SQL injection and use proper string escaping, your query should look like this:

```
var  username = req.body.username;
var  password = req.body.password;


connection.query('USE one');
  connection.query("INSERT INTO users(id,name,pass) VALUES (1,?,?)", [username, password],
    function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
    }
);
```